# Pip messed up in Anaconda Python

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have been getting recently this error in my Anaconda Python installation in my `MacOS 10.10.4`.

I tried un-installing and then re-installing `pip` but that did not work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/manabchetia/anaconda/bin/pip", line 4, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    import pip._vendor.packaging.version
ImportError: No module named packaging.version
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what lead to this error? `conda install pip`?

Comment: I was trying to install a package that was not available in `conda install` but was available in `pip install`. So running `pip install <package-name>` gave me the error.

Comment: have you tried to reinstall or update `pip` or to install your package using `easy_install` ??

Comment: `easy_install` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `conda install -f pip`.